# My custom css are not getting picked up completely

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

I have created a custom css for tree and other widgets.

I have made the following entry

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
<stylesheet src="CustomStylesheet.css" />
```

But still only some of the styles are getting picked up and others don't. Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be either one of the below,

Either you have to use [CSS Resource](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource) as mentioned by Andrew or you have missed [Doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) declaration.

You can also visit this link:  [doctype explantion w.r.t to GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641866/which-doctype-should-i-use-for-gwt-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

you should write the same style classnames with  "com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTree.css" css file and you may change content css

```
pulic class MyClass extends Composite {
   public interface MyResources extends CellTree.Resources {

        @ImageResource.ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
        @Source("cellTreeClosedItem.gif")
        ImageResource cellTreeClosedItem();

        @ImageResource.ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
        @Source("cellTreeOpenItem.gif")
        ImageResource cellTreeOpenItem();

        @Override
        @Source({"com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTree.css"})
        CellTree.Style cellTreeStyle();
    }

    private MyResources res = GWT.create(MyResources.class);


    public void onInitialize(){
        cellTree = new CellTree(treeViewModel, null, res);
    }
}
```